# Audio Fingerprinting

Tags: audio

I am doing the project in audio fingerprinting, in that after I convert the signal into mono, I have to apply the hanning window, the size of the window is 370ms, and I have to overlap the signal with a factor of P=28/32.

How can i do that?

What is meant by 28/32?

How can I overlap this signal with this overlapping factor?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 7):

> How can i do that?

Generate a 370 ms long Hann window, take a 370 ms chunk of your audio, then multiply them together, sample-by-sample.  You're just taking a chunk of audio and fading it in and out at the ends to get rid of any glitches at the start and stop of the chunk.

> What is meant by 28/32?

I'm not sure.  I'd guess it means that the waveforms overlap by 28/32 = 87.5%.  This just means that the chunks of audio you read should overlap with chunks you've already read.

Presumably your sample rate is 44100 Hz, and the window length is 2<sup>14</sup> = 16384 samples = 371.5 ms?  So

1. Generate a 16384-point Hann window and store it in memory
2. Read audio from sample 0 to sample 16383
3. Multiply them together to get a windowed chunk
4. Do FFT or whatever other processing on the windowed chunk
5. Read audio from sample ~2048 to 2048 + 16384 (87.% overlap with previous chunk)
6. Multiply with window to get a windowed chunk
7. Do FFT or whatever
8. Read audio from sample ~4096 to 4096 + 16384
9. ...

The numbers are probably off-by-one, but you get the idea.

Comment: What does this represent: ~2048 in ~2048 to 2048 for an audio buffer? If the data is from i = 0 to i < bufferSize/blockSize, where does the ~2048 exist?

Comment: @Helium3: 2048 is the time offset required to get 87.5% overlap of a 16384 sample window. (16384-2048)/16384 = 87.5%